# Embeding flash in WebKit for pygtk on windows

Tags: python, windows

I am looking for a way to play video streams with python. I couldn't find anything nice, so I ended up embedding webkit inside a gtk window, and streaming the video in there. it works well, but feels rather hacky to me.

So, my question(s):

Is there any other way to stream video (youtube, justin tv) using python and gtk?

If not, is there a way to make my code run on Windows? Currently it only runs on Linux, I suspect because of a lack of Flash support for GTK on windows. Are there any efforts being made to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALright, I've come up with an answer.

Instead of using webkit, which doesn't seem to have flash support on windows, I'm gonna use the chromium embedded framework. It should let me do what I need to do, which is embed flash in a desktop app, whilst also allowing for the option of a html based interface.

It's open source, and supports flash on windows(and linux, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **`GStreamer`** (python package)

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

Its an open source multimedia framework.
There are also articles about RTP streaming using `GStreamer` in below links

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp.html
http://eetimes.com/design/signal-processing-dsp/4004620/DSP-video-processing-via-open-sourceAPIs

There is also a streaming media server built using `GStreamer` (with LGPL license).
http://www.flumotion.net/

**PS:** if you are keen on using Adobe AIR to build a cross platform flash player below mentioned link will be at your rescue.

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208528

I myself haven't built this app, however had researched it earlier to build one. Hope it would be useful.

Comment: I've looked at gstreamer before.I'm not looking to stream data, i'm looking to consume it. There's also the issue with getting the RTMP address from sites like twitch.tv. What may work now can easily break should they decide to change something on their end. I don't like that sort of dependency.

Comment: There is also a link to play flash files using Adobe AIR :-)